# Getting issues with uitabbarcontroller is pushing from uiviewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

My application has following flow
ViewController1--->ViewController2--->TabBarController
TabBarController--->ViewController3-->ViewController7
-->ViewController4-->ViewController8
-->ViewController5
-->ViewController6
In `TabBarController`I am adding NavigationController to each ViewController.
But I am getting issues with `navigationItem` Title and rightBarButtonItem and backButtonItem
Here I want hide the backButton in the `ViewController3`,If I hides the backButton, then it disappears in the `ViewController7` also and the `navigationItem` Title shows the ViewController6  `navigationItem` Title after click on the all the tabs.
Can anyone tell me How to resolve it.? I am getting strucked with this problem from last 4 days. I tried with every sample code is given from different sites.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a functionality of NavigationController. if you set style to NavigationControllerItems, it will reflect all upcoming controller.
if you want to remove this, then you will set style for each controller separately inside viewDidLoad Method.
if you hide backButton in the ViewController3, now unhide backButton in the ViewController7.

Comment: I am unhiding the back button in ViewController7 but its not working Sumit

Comment: If I unhide the back button in ViewController7 then it will shows back button when an action is performing it goes to ViewController2.

Comment: Ok,then unhide a back button in ViewController3 inside prepareForSegue method.
another approach is to create custom NavigationBar for each ViewController and defien style as per requirement and hide default navigationBar also.

Comment: I just hidden the TabBarController's navigationBar then its working properly.